# Instagram API Update - How to use new API

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

My requirement is to create slide show of different users media. Till now, I have stored 250+ users(propertys) Instagram username and password on server for creating photo gallery of every user and showing on website one by one.

But now based on new update It requires client Id and access token to fetch each user's media content. *How to proceed with this?*

I have gone through documentation once, there is no such option for me to create and submit my application for review

[Application for public content gives error!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3Y5B.png)

Do I have to go through every user and sign up as developer store their Client ID and password?

Answer (score 0):

No just need client id and redirect URL this info user find in manage client or create new client from Instagram account then after you can generate **ACCESS TOKEN** check API example.

call in your browser url

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id="enterclientid"&scope=basic+public_content&redirect_uri="redirect_url"&response_type=token
```

in url change this info
client_id=enter your client id.
redirect_uri=The redirect_uri specifies where we redirect users after they have chosen whether or not to authenticate your application.

Disable the Client-Side (Implicit) OAuth flow for web apps. If you check this option, Instagram will better protect your application by only allowing authorization requests that use the Server-Side (Explicit) OAuth flow. The Server-Side flow is considered more secure. See the Authentication documentation for details.

New API More Info: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/

New API:https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN